# Mono P/Invoke __icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific crash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, pinvoke

I am making an interop call from mono and get this exception and runtime crashes. Do any one have any idea what can be the reason behing it?

One more my.so is internally calling libjvm.so

at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int) <0x00004>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int) <0x00004>
  at X.Y.Z.Convert (object[]) [0x00010] in /home/interopTest/XYZ.cs:104

at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void_*this*_ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

```
/usr/bin/mono() [0x80d4d0b]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x810ffeb]
/home/qctest7/Desktop/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(+0x532556) [0xb31f4556]
/home/qctest7/Desktop/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(+0x52f703) [0xb31f1703]
/home/qctest7/Desktop/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(JVM_handle_linux_signal+0x188) [0xb31f5318]
/home/qctest7/Desktop/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(+0x52f624) [0xb31f1624]
[0xb78b640c]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8214917]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x820e650]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x820d892]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x820f588]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x820f987]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x820fc8c]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x821013c]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8212eb6]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8216ce0]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8214c70]
/usr/bin/mono(mono_array_new_specific+0xd2) [0x813c152]
[0xb5911615]
[0xb4089132]
[0xb4089b90]
[0x6d3a27a6]
[0xb40d8ac1]
[0xb408e125]
[0xb408c4f4]
[0xb40d7ee8]
[0xb4eefadf]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8061328]
/usr/bin/mono(mono_runtime_invoke+0x40) [0x813c890]
/usr/bin/mono(mono_runtime_delegate_invoke+0x34) [0x813cb14]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x81b12af]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x81e8e4e]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8214f85]
/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x5cc9) [0xb77b0cc9]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0xb76f76ae]
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, your code for the P/Invoke and the invoked function signature.

Comment: Erm... if you're using interop to bridge to java, why don't you look at IKVM? http://www.mono-project.com/Java